# VS2015 error when using Shared Project project template - Unable to cast ProjectNode to IVsAggeregatableProject

Tags: visual-studio-2015, shared-project

I've added some shared projects to my solution.

But every time I right-click to add a folder or item I'm getting the error "Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.ProjectNode' to type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsAggeregatableProject'".

The strange thing however is after clicking ok, I can use everything just fine.

What's happening here?

Comment: It seems that it has to do with the Syncfusion library I use. I created a support ticket and will keep you all posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys,

With the supperb help of Syncfusion we've got this problem solved.

The Syncfusion Item Templates caused the error and they provided me an update. I checked it, and it's gone. :D

I have a Direct-Trac link with the [solution](http://www.syncfusion.com/support/directtrac/incidents/146060).

Thank you again very much Syncfusion.

Comment: Hello. Can you please share the solution? It seems that your link is not public. I installed Syncfusion's Essential Studio yesterday and I'm getting the same error message. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I will do it right now.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was occurred from the Syncfusion Item Templates Utility, since command is not enabled properly while right click on the Project Node in Shared project. Please uninstall and reinstall the Syncfusion Item Templates VSIX from your Visual Studio and install the modified VSIX from the below location.

Download the modified VSIX from [here](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/146060/ze/SyncfusionItemTemplates-353297916) and perform the below steps to reinstall the Syncfusion Item Templates VSIX.

1. From Visual Studio, navigate to Tools->Extension and Updates.
2. Select Syncfusion Item Templates and perform uninstallation.
3. Close the Visual Studio.
4. Run the downloaded Extension by double clicking on the new VSIX and install it. Once installed, open Visual Studio and continue.
5. Now there will not be any error messages on project right click.

Note: If you are unable to uninstall the Syncfusion Item Templates VSIX, please try out these steps in Visual Studio Administrator mode.